# Rewriting Queries and data layers

Tags: database, vitess

I was going through the following question in quora :

https://www.quora.com/How-was-YouTube-programmed-in-Python

The first answer here mentioned about a software named "Vitess " . It mentioned that vitess rewrites queries and so provides optimization . 
What exactly does it mean to rewrite queries for optimization of database transactions . I have read about few software having their own customized RDBMS systems and layering of data for making database operations faster .

How exactly can rewriting queries make the operations faster ?
With the fear of broadening of the scope of this question , I would request some insights on layering of data and materials where I can start from to know more about data layering and rewriting of queries.

Answer (score 0):

I work on [vitess](http://vitess.io).

If an optimization was universally viable, then the database engine would itself do it.

The types of optimizations that Vitess performs are trade-offs that are viable for today's applications. For example:

- For OLTP workloads, Vitess adds a limit clause to your query. If the number of rows exceeds certain amount, it returns an error.
- If a query is taking too long to complete, it's most likely causing harm to other queries. So, we kill such queries in order to keep the system going.
- We rewrite DMLs to be primary key based. This way, the replicas don't have to redo the original work. This is applicable if you're using statement based replication.
- If two identical queries hit the system, send only one and share the results.

These are just some highlights. We've added many more such tuning options based on problems and outages we've seen at YouTube.